# Selection of identical elements

Tags: combinations

Let's say there are 5 identical elements, how many ways of selection can I have if I would like to select 
(i) 1 element from that? 
(ii) 2 elements from that?

My understanding is that since all the elements are identical, so no matter how many elements I select, the way is only 1.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don’t see a reason why it could be incorrect.